# How to get a file to move on to the next line using a for loop

Tags: c++, file, for-loop

So, I've been having an issue where my program is trying to read a file, "LineUp.txt", and I organized the file to have the names alphabetical, but it won't read more than one name, it just reads the first name over and over. I'm using a for loop, not a while loop, which I haven't seen before in other problems. I appreciate the help! Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main (){

    ifstream myFile;
    string name, front, back;
    int numOfStudents, i;

    myFile.open("LineUp.txt");

    if(!myFile)
        cout << "File not found";

    cout << "Please enter the number of students: ";
    cin >> numOfStudents;

    myFile >> name;

    front = name;

    back = name;

    while(myFile >> name){

        if(name < front)
            front = name;

        if(name > back)
            back = name;

    }

    for(i = 0; i < numOfStudents; i++){

        myFile >> name;

        cout << name << endl;

    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `while` loop will read *all* the contents of the file. The following `for` loop will attempt to read from beyond EOF. If you add a check for that in the `for` loops condition (like e.g. `i < numOfStudents && myFile >> name`) then you will see that it will not run at all.

Comment: how do I go back to the beginning of the file?

Comment: Did you try reading your C++ book, it explains how to use `std::ifstream`.

Comment: It didn't talk about using for loops with files, which is what I'm doing

Comment: Reading from a file, writing to a file, and reposition to the beginning of the file, has absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with loops. You can do every one of those things without any kind of a loop anywhere in the picture. By the way, did you hear about this amazing web site called www.google.com? All I had to do is type `std::ifstream reposition`, and out popped out a bunch of links, the very first one being an example of doing this exact same thing.

Comment: I was asking because @someprogrammerdude mentioned doing that, and it's the best thing I've got on what to do next

Comment: ah, thanks! I did google things for a long time, like an hour, but all of them used while loops, that's why I asked my question.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop would exhaust your input stream.

If you want to read from the file again you would have to create a new input stream.

```
myFile.open("LineUp.txt");

if(!myFile)
    cout << "File not found";

cout << "Please enter the number of students: ";
cin >> numOfStudents;

myFile >> name;

front = name;

back = name;

while(myFile >> name){

    if(name < front)
        front = name;

    if(name > back)
        back = name;

}

ifstream myFile2("LineUp.txt"); //Create a new stream

for(i = 0; i < numOfStudents; i++){

    myFile2 >> name;

    cout << name << endl;

}
```

Comment: only issue, the file isn't organized anymore, and that was the point of the first file stream

Comment: @FreckledTerror97 The first loop entirely operates in memory. It doesn't write back to the file. In fact it doesn't really re-order anything. All it does is keep track of the first and last names found. Consider as an alternative reading the file into a `std::vector`, arranging the contents of the `vector` to taste (`std::sort` can help here), then printing out the contents of the `vector`.

Comment: It's a homework problem, it isn't supposed to use a vector